# customError not picking up error page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have the following in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

I have an Error Controller with:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

404 seems to work, but for any other error the application keeps going to:

```
localhost/Error
```

It drops the application name from the url.  I tried adding it into the defaultRedirect = "~/MyApp/Error" also tried to make it "~/Error1" instead of "Error" just to check, but in both cases any error would go to localhost/Error.

Do I need to do something extra?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Ugh..my fault I see why I was always going to localhost/Error, there was an ajax call which was redirecting to Error, I adjusted it and now it's fine.